# How to use String methods on java.util.stream.Stream lines

Tags: java

I'd like to use the Stream API to compact some existing functions I have. I have a doubt on how to call functions on the lines I'm streaming.
For example, take the following snippet:

```
String str = "abcdef"; 
Stream<String> lines = str.lines();
lines.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is it possible to invoke String methods on each line?
for example, instead of just printing the raw line, I want to print the toUpperCase() of it.
So that the output is:

```
ABCDEF
```

Is there a way to plug the toUpperCase() function in this line:

```
lines.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

```
lines.forEach(line -> System.out.println(line.toUpperCase());
```

or

```
lines.map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks!! it was worth losing some reputation to learn it.